Has there ever been a case where elephants are carried by aircraft?
I know that today's aircraft can carry very large amounts of cargo, and some (presumably military heavy transport aircraft) can even carry tanks.
However, I've been thinking, has there ever been an occasion where live, adult (mature) elephants are transported by aircraft?
In terms of weight, most elephants don't exceed the maximum weight of large cargo aircraft. But has there really been an air transport of elephants in aviation history?
Would that even be possible? Wouldn't a grumpy elephant (and they most likely will be grumpy for being squeezed into a tight cargo hold) cause the aircraft to crash?
I mean, the slightest movement of an elephant that weighs more than 3 tons would most likely cause the aircraft to roll, pitch, or drop, and may even break the fuselage if the elephant's force is great enough.
So, my question is, has there been such an occasion? And if there isn't, is this even possible?
Thanks for any insights on this!

It seems highly unlikely that an elephant would just be shoved into a wide-open cargo hold and allowed to roam freely during flight. The obvious move is to put it into a crate that’s just big enough, and then fix that crate in place after loading (like any other large/heavy load) so it can’t move around enough to cause problems during flight.

@nobody I know that, and I apologize for any misunderstanding or confusion of me asking if they are put into the aircraft cargo hold without any restraints. It's just that I originally though they may bring down an aircraft even if the elephant is inside a crate and secured. Do you suggest any edits that can convey my question more clearly for future viewers? Thanks in advance!

There have been things more complex than that transported in cargo holds, including whale sharks, in their tank. See for instance https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uveltPY1LHk

@jcaron That's easy, you just need a tank made of transparent aluminum. (And a transporter.)

I recall a Texas Billionaire moving an entire herd of elephants from Africa to Texas, either in the late eighties or early nineties, for his personal perusal.  Don't recall the man's name, but I remember it was filmed either on 60 Minutes or 20/20.

@JohnHunt: Doesn't necessarily mean they were moved by air; Africa to Texas could easily be done by ship.

@Vikki This is begging the question (the elephant in the room! ) of why they are doing it by plane, considering how expensive it is. Look at WPNSGuy's answer: from Puerto Rico to Jacksonville seems very doable, as there are no long parts on land (unlike the transfer from Islamabad) and the climate must be good (unlike the one from Anchorage). I suppose the elephant would suffer too much if kept inside a tight cage for too long. A ship could go from Puerto Rico to Jacksonville in 2-3 days. If that's too long, I wonder how long an elephant can resist.

Transporting an elephant is not a problem. Its called sedation/tranquilizer.

I know for a fact that black rhinos were, at least historically, regularly airlifted (upside down no less) by comparatively small helicopters with some regularity as part of relocating them for conservation efforts. I would actually be a bit amazed if something similar has never been done with an elephant (a S-64 or an Mi-10 could easily handle even the biggest ones if they were sedated).

PS elephants weight from 2000 - 6000 kg so there's quite a variation.  (Height 10-13 feet.)

@Vicki;  The animals were shown being unloaded from a modified cargo plane. Wish I could recall the specifics.

@FabiosaysReinstateMonica; The purpose given for the Texas event was the billionaire's desire to protect the species. I'm sure it had nothing to do with his ego.

Pakistan to Cambodia. DHL.
https://www.stattimes.com/news/dhl-safely-relocates-the-worlds-loneliest-elephant-air-cargo/?infinitescroll=1

the first adult elephant to board an airplane in Pakistan

Puerto Rico to Jacksonville FL. Atlas Air 747. https://www.jacksonville.com/picture-gallery/news/2023/05/12/puerto-rican-zoo-animals-flown-jacksonville-way-new-homes/11858127002/

a cargo of one elephant, one rhinoceros, a hippopotamus, a donkey and an impala

Elmendorf AFB, AK to San Andreas, CA. USAF C-17. https://www.af.mil/News/Article-Display/Article/125251/pachyderm-pcs-elephant-finds-new-home-courtesy-of-air-force/

"We contacted local authorities in Anchorage and began the lengthy process of requesting an Air Force flight for Maggie," said Pat Derby, PAWS co-founder and president, who agreed to reimburse the Air Force. "After several weeks of negotiating, we secured permission from the Air Force to fly Maggie for a price -- between \$215,000 and \$300,000."


Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Your answer is very informative and helpful. Again, thanks for the great answer!

And that wasn't a full list just the first few I came across. There have been others.

Really? So elephants can really be transported inside aircraft rather easily.

Well, not "easily". Specialized crate, lots of training, lots of money. But is IS done.

I do have a question though: are they tranquilized, or are they just secured inside a large crate and loaded into the aircraft?

An elephant beverage cart can be developed.

@AircraftEnthusiast007 Maggie is awake during the flight

I thought they had flown elephants on C-46s over the Burma hump in WWII, but it looks like the elephants walked to China. They did, however, fly 3000 mules. "The airlift brought about 3,000 mules over the Hump, mostly for the Chinese army. They rode four mules to a transport, with four Chinese “cowboys” keeping them under control. Crew members said it took a day to clear the smell out of the airplanes." https://www.airandspaceforces.com/article/1009hump/

fantastic answer @WPNSGuy .  elephants weigh from 2000 - 6000 kg so there's quite a variation, i wonder if any weights available from the known cases.  6k is much different from 2k i guess.

If I'm not mistaken TANKS weigh 20-50 ton and they regularly go in air transport .. is that right?  (I appreciate the issue is the object wiggling around.)

Apparently the abrams tank (the "usual" current US tank) is 65t and it can go by C17. Sounds like you could take 10 or 20 elephants !!

@Fattie - Weightwise, a C-17 could take a dozen or so elephants. Not so sure about spacewise, once you include the crates they ride in.

Operation Dumbo Drop. USAF C-130. U.S. Air Force Press Release
Nah Trong, Vietnam to Chu Lai
April 1, 1968
2 Elephants, one at a time, were flown on a C-130 from Nah Trong, Vietnam to Chu Lai to help villagers move trees. They were sedated during the trip so they wouldn't move. They were then moved from Chu Lai to the village with a CH-53 helicopter.

DIRECTORATE OF INFORMATION, Headquarters Seventh Air Force TAN SON
NHUT AIR BASE REPUBLIC OF VIETNAM APO San Francisco 96307
FOR IMMEDIATE RELEASE 4-68-40
AIR FORCE FLIES ELEPHANT AIRLIFT
NHA TRANG (AF)
Air Force C-130 Hercules transport crews are used to flying
almost anything you can name. Even elephants. Flying elephants isn't
easy. It takes the help of the U.S. Arny Special Forces, the Marine
Corps, the United States Agency for International Development (USAID),
the Cleveland Zoo and the U. S. Bureau of Narcotics. It all began when
an Army Special Forces team at the diminutive Vietnamese village of
Tra Bong offered to help the 400 Montagnard and Vietnamese families in
the area start their own industry. With the heavy growths of timber in
the area, a sawmill looked like the answer to the villagers' economic
problems, and with the help of USAID, the villagers soon had a
burgeoning business going. Before long, however, the villagers had cut
down all the trees near enough to the sawmill to haul by hand, and a
problem arose. The local terrain was so rugged that machinery for
hauling logs was useless. Tra Bong was in danger of losing its only
industry, Elephants, the villagers said, were the only answer. Two
suitable elephants were found and with the help of USAID funds,
purchased at a price of 70,000 piastors (about $590) each.
Unfortunately, however, the elephants were located in Ban Don, more
than 170 miles from Tre Bang. The pachyderms couldn't be transported
by land because the trip was too long and the Viet Cong controlled too
much of the intervening territory. A move by sea was ruled out because
it would also take too long and there was the danger of the elephants
becoming seasick. The only way to move the 3-ton, 6-foot-high animals,
it appeared, was by air.
Special Forces Captain Scott Gantt, the man given the job of moving
the elephants, decided to call on the Air Force. When Gantt approached
7th Air Force with his project, he was told that the elephants could
easily be moved in the cavernous C-130 Hercules cargo transports,
provided the animals could be immobilized enough to prevent their
thrashing around in the aircraft.
After hours of transoceanic phone calls, Gantt finally learned from
the Cleveland Zoo that a drug called M-99, manufactured by an English
firm, would keep his 6,000-pound charges docile for the necessary
time. When Cantt arranged for a shipment of M-99, however, he ran
afoul of the U. S. Bureau of Narcotics, which demanded that he spell
out how the drug was to be used before it could be shipped.
Gantt complied, the drug arrived, and on April 1 a C-130 crew from
Task Force Bravo, a special airlift mission based at Nha Trang Air
Base, landed their aircraft on a dirt strip near the Special Forces
camp of Trang Phuc and prepared to take on board their most unusual
passengers ever. While the first of the animals stood on a cargo net,
Gantt Stood behind him and fired a hypodermic dart from an air gun
into the elephant's rump, injecting him with the K-99. Five minutes
later, "Clyde," as the Green Berets had nicknamed him, lay dosing
peacefully in the net. A forklift hoisted him onto a wooden platform
and lifted him into the gaping rear doors of the waiting C-130.
With Clyde strapped firmly in place, the Hercules crew took off for
the Marine Air Base at Chu Lai, 20 miles from Tra Bong. At Chu Lai,
Clyde was removed from the C-130 and still wrapped in the cargo net on
his platform, was slung beneath a Marine CH-53 "Super Jolly Green
Giant" for the final miles of his trip. The chopper whirled away in a
blast of sand and dust, and 15 minutes later Clyde was settling to the
ground at Tra Bong in front of the watchful eyes of more than 2,000
villagers. Then, after a repeat of the first trip with Clyde's
partner, the village and the sawmill were back in the lumber business.


I'm absolutely gobsmacked to discover that the movie was really based on a true story!

I wonder if the people who named the operation had watched the Disney movie Dumbo when they were kids. This operation is an interesting one, and the name almost certainly has some kind of reference to the Disney movie.

Dumbo was released in 1941, the mission was in the 70s, so it's certainly conceivable that some of the people involved had been kids when the film came out, and many of the older folks probably had kids who were the right age to go see it. Anyway, by the 70s, Dumbo was deeply ingrained in the cultural mind. If you're planning a mission that's going to make an elephant fly, the name writes itself.

Back in 2016, a 747 flew a total of 17 elephants from Swaziland to zoos in Texas, Kansas, and Nebraska

The plane, which brought 17 elephants from Swaziland and dropped five off in Dallas early Friday morning, arrived at Wichita Eisenhower National Airport at 12:31 p.m. Friday with its controversial cargo. The final six elephants are destined for the Henry Doorly Zoo in Omaha.


The large crates containing the elephants were tightly enclosed, with narrow slits providing ventilation but not much of a view for the crowd gathered outside the fence. That didn’t dim the enthusiasm much, though.


Veterinarians aboard the overseas flight reported that the elephants were eating, drinking and, in some cases, sleeping, Dennis Pate, executive director and CEO of Omaha’s Henry Doorly Zoo and Aquarium, said in a statement.
Graham characterized the relocation effort as “part of an ongoing rescue mission to provide safe haven and a more secure future” for the elephants.

Video of unloading elephants from the airplane



Related news articles
https://www.kansas.com/news/local/article65247617.html
https://www.cbsnews.com/texas/news/african-elephants-arrive-on-special-747-bound-for-the-dallas-zoo/

"Eating, drinking,..."   And what else? :)

Cargolux is a cargo-only airline based in, you guessed it, tiny Luxembourg. And in 2012, it flew an elephant that had arrived in Luxembourg by truck to Pittsburgh zoo:

On Tuesday a Cargolux plane takes off from Luxembourg bound for New York with a very special passenger onboard: Thabo-Umasai a five year old elephant born Dresden zoo in Germany will make the trip to his new home in Pittsburgh Zoo as his current German home lacks the space to house him.
The animal will arrive in Luxembourg by truck before flying to the United States. A delicate operation, as Thabo weighs 1.9 tons and measures 2.20 meters.

Cargolux regularly flies special cargo, like racing horses, typically accompanied by veterinarians. The source does not say, but I could imagine Thabo to have been sedated and similarly accompanied during his trip.

Here's a video:




Here's a new story about a pile of elephants on a flight (not much actual video of the cage etc),




It would improve the answer to include some key details like year, air carrier / plane info, departure and arrival airports, name of elephant, etc.  As-is, this is basically a link-only answer, plus maybe the thumbnails, although if the video links rot they'll also die I assume.

quite so @PeterCordes , it's a tricky one since it's a "let me google that" question, although a fun question.  We're a quarter way in to the 21st century.  All you have to do at any point on Earth is speak in to the air "give me all information about elephants on airliners" and you will instantly get every video ever of this happening, and indeed these days, a poorly-written spoken "AI" summary of the dates etc. So I think it's sort of horses for courses, IDK. On a more serious engineering-like question what you say is certainly the case.
